# How to set Firebase (not set) in Analytics?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, google-analytics

We have a react native app nad we are using Firebase for analytics. Mostly it is working. We have 2 custom dimensions as you see on screenshot below SubMenu and CustomData. Stats on Screenshot are older than 24 hours.

[image]

While most CustomData is set, some are (not set). I dont understand how and why. On my local tests it always gives the expected result, however on our live Analytics some values are (not set). Lets say CustomData is a car brand, row 64 and 69 both have Mercedes. The app logs 64 as Mercedes but 69 (not set). How can I debug this or find out what is the right value? Where might I need to modify the code?

Below is the code part regarding Firebase Analytics:

In App.tsx:

```
const FirebaseComponent = () => {
    const loggedIn = useSelector<RootState>(state => state.auth.loggedIn);
    const id = useSelector<RootState, number>(state => state.user.id);
    const customDataName = useSelector<RootState, string>(state => state.user?.customData?.name);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (loggedIn && id && customDataName) {
            FirebaseAnalytics.setUserId(id);
            FirebaseAnalytics.setmyAppUserProperties(customDataName);
            FirebaseAnalytics.logAppInstanceId();
        }
    }, [loggedIn, id, customDataName]);

    return null;
};
```

In FirebaseAnalytics.module.ts

```
import { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/analytics";

    analytics = firebase.analytics();
    
    public async setmyAppUserProperties(customDataName: string,) {
        const networkCarrier = await DeviceInfo.getCarrier();
        const networkInformation = await NetInfo.fetch();

        this.analytics.setUserProperties({
            network_carrier: networkCarrier,
            network_connection: networkInformation.type,
            customDataName: customDataName
        }).catch((err) => console.log('Error when setting user properties: ', err));
    }
```

`customDataName` becomes sometimes (not set)

I appreciate any kind of hint!